# Most efficient way to get subset from a sorted list

Tags: python

I have a very long list and it is composed with tuples. One element in the tuple is time. The list is sorted by this element.

```
myList = [
    ('2018-01-01 01:00:00','a'),
    ('2018-01-01 02:00:00','b'),
    ('2018-01-01 03:00:00','c')]
```

Now I want to extract a subset of it, that is, 24 hours before '2018-01-02 01:02:03'. What is the most efficient ways to get the subset out? Right now I iterate through the whole list and it is not running fast at all!

Also please note that the time in the tuple is not a datetime object but a string... Thanks!

---- my code follows (as requested) -----

```
endTime = datetime.datetime(2018-01-01)
for i in myList:
  if endTime - datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') < datetime.timedelta(days=1):
  print i[1]
```

This code is over simplified for what I am trying to do. The tuples in my list has many more elements, and the function once condition met is a lot more complex than the "print" function. However the key is that myList is huge (30k+), and I have 12k+ "endTime" to run through my list too. Thanks.

Comment: Please could you show us the code that you have tried so far, thanks.

Comment: High level improvements: 1) Use a binary search instead of linear for O(log n) time
2) Convert all of the dates in `myList` into `datetime`s. (You can also compare dates lexographically if they follow ISO8601, but I suspect this would be slower)